# ALC892 and 5.1 Headset

Tags: windows-7, headset, 5.1

I have a XMG P501 with an ALC892 and want to use a 5.1 headset with it.
My problem is that the system use jack sharing and I can't use the same jacks for my mic, because they are used by s/c and rear.

Is there any possiblity to get it running with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked with the manufacturer of the laptop and it isn't possible to use a 5.1 headset.